# Indexing a NAS volume

Tags: spotlight, search, nas

I've just bought a [QNAP NAS](https://www.qnap.com/i/uk/product/model.php?II=143) for my Mac Pro (late 2013) running Yosemite, to replace some older direct-attached storage I'd been using previously.

I'm very happy with it so far, but one thing I didn't realise is that network-attached volumes aren't indexed by Spotlight. The NAS will be used to store thousands of PDFs documents, and I need to be able to find specific text within those documents easily.

The network share (via AFP) is mounted as Data, so I've tried:

```
$ sudo mdutil -i /Volumes/Data/
Error: unexpected indexing state (/Volumes/Data/)
```

Then

```
$ sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Data/
/Volumes/Data: 2015-08-28 17:13:21.637 mdutil[4613:183771] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/Data -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
Indexing disabled.
```

... which seems to be to suggest that the QNAP simply won't support this.

Can anyone confirm my interpretation of the above? If so, does anyone know of any software that will easily and reliably index the data (including the contents) of the documents on this volume?